# Nuget query for package information using v3 .NET API

Tags: nuget

I was following [this post](http://daveaglick.com/posts/exploring-the-nuget-v3-libraries-part-2) to find out how to query v3/v2 sources for a package using NuGet v3 API. The author shows how to add package sources using

```
Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3()
```

I couldn't get that going and had to use

```
NuGet.Protocol.Core.v2.FactoryExtensionsV2.GetCoreV2(Repository.Provider)
```

Is there a doco/sample to demonstrate how to query for a package information using v3 .NET API?

Comment: There's no good API at this point. Thankfully, there's a REST option which I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using v3 REST option. [Sharing details](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/nuget-v3-find-and-download-a-package) in case someone is looking for this info.

Answer (score 0):

I use Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3 instead

```
    private async Task<IPackageSearchMetadata> GetPkgResource(string sourceUrl= "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json", string packageId)
            {
                var sourceRepository = Repository.Factory.GetCoreV3(sourceUrl);
                var searchResource = await sourceRepository.GetResourceAsync<PackageSearchResource>();
                var searchMetadata = await searchResource.SearchAsync(packageId, new SearchFilter(false), 0, 5, new Logger(), CancellationToken.None);
                return searchMetadata?.FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension method contained in a separate package `NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3/