# Find if NuGet package has an update using .NET API v3

Tags: nuget

The samples I've found so far use either

```
repository.FindPackage()
```

or

```
repository.GetUpdates()
```

But both a v2 of the NuGet .NET API. Where can I find an example of equivalent for v3?

Comment: There's no good API at this point. Thankfully, there's a REST option which I ended up going with.

Comment: Another question of mine has this info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650195/nuget-query-for-package-information-using-v3-net-api/37866096#37866096